# Tkinter Treeview Append to List with get_children()

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tkinter, treeview

I want to 'save' the contents of the treeview into a list which I can display again. Just like 'settings'.

[image: settings example]

```
for child in self.terminal_tree.get_children():
    print(self.terminal_tree.item(child)["values"])

    machine_ports = []
    machine_ports.append(self.terminal_tree.item(child)["values"])
    print(machine_ports)
```

The output I get is:

```
['abc', 123]
[['abc', 123]]
['hjk', 456]
[['hjk', 456]]
```

The output that I want is  `[['abc', 123], ['hjk', 456]]`

Comment: This question doesn't have much to do with tkinter. It's just a mistake when populating a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put:

```
machine_ports = []
```

*above* `for` loop:

```
machine_ports = []
for child in self.terminal_tree.get_children():
    print(self.terminal_tree.item(child)["values"])
    machine_ports.append(self.terminal_tree.item(child)["values"])
    print(machine_ports)
```